# ERROR: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, vob

I want to replace the audio stream in a Video-DVD. But I have problems with the replace of the audio stream.

The DVD-VOB have 3 streams. 
Stream 0 is dvd_nav_packet.
Stream 1 is the video.
Stream 2 is the audio.

I also tryed to change the exportinformation for ffmepg with -map 0:d and -map 0:d:1. Also with and without  from the codec Infos -f vob -target ntsc-dvd -vcodec copy -acodec copy. And update ffmpeag/use older versions. But I only get error messages.

ffmpeg is startet with a vb.net Programm which which decide which video need a new audio file.

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong?

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "F:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB" -i "%CD%\tfpat.mp2" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -f vob -target ntsc-dvd -vcodec copy -acodec copy "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB"


ffmpeg version N-88514-gd5995c531d Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavformat    58.  0.102 / 58.  0.102
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.101 /  7.  0.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'F:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB':
  Duration: 00:01:51.17, start: 0.300300, bitrate: 7273 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 6800 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
[ac3 @ 037ee700] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, ac3, from 'D:\SkyDrive\Projekte\AtmosFX_Syncro_Projekt\AtmosFX-Translator\AlteVersionen\Version 2\tfpat.mp2':
  Duration: 00:01:51.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
File 'C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[dvd @ 037fbd20] Invalid media type data for output stream #0
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg will not copy over the existing navigation packet, so skip it.

`ffmpeg.exe -i "F:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB" -i "%CD%\tfpat.mp2" -map 0:v -map 1:a -f vob -target ntsc-dvd -vcodec copy -acodec copy "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. The thing is that I have already managed it so far. But when I burned the DVD, the sequence of the videos wasn't right anymore. The videos got mixed up. So after a long time I found out that Stream 0 was missing.  Therefore I assume that this is also the reason why the DVD doesn't work like the template anymore. My goal is to translate the DVD in a new language.